# Python | Pandas | Using Lambda multiple conditions to calculate rows with values and NAN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, lambda

I am trying to do a python pandas function to calculate the number of instances vs "Customer Name" and "Customer ID" and "Number of tickets".

I have noticed that in some rows the user ID was not present despite having a ticket and customer name. 
I want to have a table with the sum of tickets (rows) that were opened by a customer name and had no customer ID.

I expect getting a table similar to the below:

[image]

I used the lambada function:

```
for  CustomertID in CustomerIDList:


CustomerID_Series=ExlReport.apply(lambda x:True if x['Account Name'] == CustomerID  else False, axis=1)
numOfRows = len(CustomerID_Series[CustomerID_Series == True].index)
countList.append(numOfRows)
```

I get the output below:

[image]

So my question: 
How to use lambda to have multiple conditions based on Customer Name and Customer ID and to sum the rows counts / ticket numbers of: 
1) Customer Name is found but no customer ID.
2) Customer name and customer ID found.

I thought of using for loop on the customer name instead of customer id list, but I am confused on how to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get any answer on this question, however I solved it myself without using lambada and without using for loops. Adding the solution for reference:

I replaced the empty cells in 'customer ID' by a string value of 'N/A' and used 'group by' and 'size()' to get ticket count.

Solution as below:

***1- Sorted the df to have the empty cell / cells with NAN value first:***

```
df = (df[['Customer Name','Customer ID']]).sort_values(by=["Customer Name","Customer ID"],axis = 0,ascending = [True,True],na_position='first')
```

***2- Replace the empty cell in column 'Customer ID' with a string of 'N/A':***

```
df['Customer ID'] = df['Customer ID'].replace(np.nan, 'N/A')
```

***3- Use group by to group the df by the two columns, priority is given to "Customer Name"***

***4- size will be used to count of the Rows***

***5- Reset index is needed to add column name "Ticket Count" to df:***

```
df = ((df.***groupby***(["Customer Name","Customer ID"],as_index = False)).***size()***.***reset_index(name="Ticket Count"***))
```

**6- Replaced the 'N/A' with '':**

```
df["Customer ID"] = df["Customer ID"].replace('N/A','')
```

**7- Output similar to the below:** 
[image: Output]